# How can I push my code to a new repository on Github in Intellij?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

In Intellij, I created a new project from version control. I have made changes to this code and want to upload it to my own repo. Looking back, I should have cloned it rather than creating it from version control, but is there any way for me to push what I have to my own Github?

Comment: I know nothing about Intellij, but the usual thing is, certainly: create a github repo, add it as a rmote to your own repo, and push. That is how I make github repos all the time; I never start _at_ github, I start on my computer.

Comment: @matt I do see an option in Intellij for remotes. When I click it, it brings up a box that allows me to enter url's - currently the only one there is the URL I originally pulled from and it is set as origin. If I create a new repo then add it, it should push to my personal repo? Thank you for your time by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Add a remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/set-up-a-git-repository.html#add-remote).
2. Push to this remote.

[image: Add Remote]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I'll set it as the correct answer as soon as the time is up.